# Request for exercises on Stiefel-Whitney classes

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

Where can I find a list of exercises on Stiefel-Whitney classes? I see there are a few in Spanier on $q$-sphere bundles and a few in M&S. Optimally there would be a list of questions that start easy and then progress gradually.